# vanilla javascript classList manipulation on hover

Tags: javascript, html, load, classname

Trying to do some really basic class manipulation on hover and load for a splash page. Not sure why it's not working- then again, never written in Vanilla before.

[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/hXjFz/).

basic DOM:

```
<body>
    <article>
        <p>test</p>
    </article>
</body>
```

JavaScript:

```
var bod     = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0],
    article = document.getElementsByTagName('article')[0];

article.onMouseOver = function(){

    bod.classList.add('focus');
}

article.onMouseOut = function(){

    bod.classList.remove('focus');
}

window.onLoad = function(){

    bod.classList.remove('loading');
}
```

Comment: If you're looking for vanilla, you should use CSS only: `article:hover`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

use lowercase handlers:

```
article.onmouseover
```

But in general it's better to use the `addEventListener` method.
The .onevent method allows for only one handler and its also quick and dirty. however it messes up the code and the html and in some cases you might even remove some other important code from running, that is why the `addEventListener` is better, as it chains and you can have multiple handlers listening to one event, which is the proper form.

Here is a wonderful answer from another stackoverflow user on the exact differences (however I pretty much sum it up for you in the above paragraph)..
[AddEventListener vs element.onevent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6348494/addeventlistener-vs-onclick)

here is the fixed Fiddle using the proper event handling:
http://jsfiddle.net/hXjFz/1/

Comment: all good. answered at the same time- will still give you credit as you're correct. thanks for the help.

Answer (score 3):

I'm an idiot. Handlers arn't camelCased.

```
article.onmouseover;
article.onmouseout;
window.onload;
```

Comment: yes but you shouldn't use those either..better use addEventListener so you and others can chain..

Comment: @dory i have no need to chain in this case, so short and sweet is preferred. but if you'd like to link to a jsfiddle for others reference i'm sure there will be kudos involved.

Comment: hey I'm just trying to answer this question properly :) you decide what's good for you...I used the .onsomething many times when I'm too lazy or running something quick and dirty. anyhow, I added the answer.